# problem with mschart in winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am big problem for drawing two different charts on the same form...

I have one form, in that form i have represented the pie chart with data coming from database that was working fine.....

and i have managed that when i click on the specific part on the pie chart i want to show two different graphs .. upto click event i have managaed but I am not able to show two different charts ....

and this is my below code...

```
public void mschart1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // here i am checking the condition to hit the exact location in chart

    Series serries;
    Series series2 = null;
    DataTable new1 = null; 
    new1  = mData.accountstatus(); 

    DataTable new2 = null; 
    new2 = mdata2.Totals(dtpStartDate.Value, dtpenddate.Value); 

    mschart1.ChartAreas.Clear(); 
    mschart1.Titles.Clear(); 
    mschart1.Series.Clear(); 

    area = "area1"; 
    mschart1.ChartAreas.Add(area); 
    serries = mschart1.Series.Add(area); 
    serries.ChartArea = area; 

    title = mschart1.Titles.Add("title1"); 
    title.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold); 
    title.Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft; 
    title.DockedToChartArea = area; 

    mschart1.Titles.Add("").DockedToChartArea = area; 

    area = "area2"; 
    mschart1.ChartAreas.Add(area); 
    series2 = mschart1.Series.Add(area); 
    series2.ChartArea = area; 

    title = mschart1.Titles.Add("title2"); 
    title.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold); 
    title.Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft; 
    title.DockedToChartArea = area; 

    mschart1.Titles.Add("").DockedToChartArea = area; 

    foreach (Title chartTitle in mschart1.Titles) 
    { 
        chartTitle.IsDockedInsideChartArea = false; 
    } 

    foreach (ChartArea chartArea in mschart1.ChartAreas) 
    { 
        chartArea.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true; 
        chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true; 
    } 

    if (area == "area2") 
    { 
        foreach (Series charttypes in mschart1.Series) 
        { 
            charttypes.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie; 
            charttypes["PielabelStyle"] = "Outside"; 
            charttypes["DoughnutRadius"] = "30"; 
            charttypes["PieDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge"; 
            charttypes.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalLeft; 
        } 
    } 

    if (area == "area1") 
    { 
        foreach (Series chartareas in mschart1.Series) 
        { 
            chartareas.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn; 
            chartareas["ColumnDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge"; 
            chartareas["LabelStyle"] = "Top"; 
            chartareas.IsValueShownAsLabel = true; 
            chartareas.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalLeft; 
        } 
    } 

    foreach (Legend legend in mschart1.Legends) 
    { 
        legend.Enabled = false; 
    } 

    if (new2 == null) 
    { 
        series2.Points.Clear(); 
        series2.Points.AddXY("no data", 0); 
    } 

    if(new1 == null) 
    { 
        serries.Points.Clear(); 
        serries.Points.AddXY("no data", 0); 
    } 
    mschart1.Series["area1"].Points.DataBindXY(new2.Rows, "data1", new2.Rows, "Value"); 
    mschart1.Series["area2"].Points.DataBindXY(new1.Rows, "name", new2.Rows, "count"); 

    if (area == "area1") 
    { 
        foreach (Series charttypes in mschart1.Series) 
        { 
            foreach (DataPoint point in charttypes.Points) 
            { 
                switch (point.AxisLabel) 
                { 
                    case "case1": point.Color = Color.Cyan; break; 
                    case "case2": point.Color = Color.Green; break; 
                } 
                point.Label = string.Format("{0:0} - {1}", point.YValues[0], point.AxisLabel); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    if (area == "area2") 
    { 
        foreach (Series chartareas in mschart1.Series) 
        { 
            foreach (DataPoint point in chartareas.Points) 
            { 
                switch (point.AxisLabel) 
                { 
                    case "case23": point.Color = Color.Green; break; 
                    case "case 24": point.Color = Color.Blue; break; 
                } 
                point.Label = string.Format("{0:0}", point.YValues[0]); 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

my problem when i click on the chart in specific area  it will shows two charts but both are same charts ..(i want two different type of charts as i have mentioned in the below code)

would any one pls help on this......

Many thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem is in the pieces (two) of code like this one:

```
if (area == "area2") 
{ 
    foreach (Series charttypes in mschart1.Series) 
    { 
       charttypes.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie; 
       ...
    }
} 
if (area == "area1") 
{ 
    foreach (Series charttypes in mschart1.Series) 
    { 
       charttypes.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn; 
       ...
    }
}
```

Since `area` variable is lastly set to `"area2"`, only the first `if` condition will be reached and so the chart type will be always of type Pie.

I think you should change your code to something like:

```
foreach (Series charttypes in mschart1.Series) 
{ 
     if(charttypes.ChartArea == "area2")
     {
       charttypes.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie; 
       ...
     }
     else if(charttypes.ChartArea == "area1")
     {
       charttypes.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn; 
       ...
     }
}
```